# Angularjs watch is not triggering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, listener, angularjs-service

I have three elements to this program.  First, in the service, I have:

```
$scope.loaded = MySvc.loaded;
$scope.loaded = false;
```

Then, in the controller which imports this service, I have a series of introductory things.  I need to trigger events in the directives once the controller is done with its asycnhronous work, so in the controller, when that trigger is ready, I do

```
MySvc.loaded = true;
```

And then in the directive, which also imports the service, I have,

```
$scope.loaded = MySvc.loaded;
$scope.$watch('loaded', function (newValue, oldValue) {
```

The directive triggers when `loaded` is initialized to 'false', but when I change the value to 'true', nothing happens.  The watch simply does not trigger.  Why not?  How do I fix this?

Comment: First of all, it's weird that service has access to the `$scope`. Can you post full source code for this situation? Probably, your directives have their own scope and therefore, the `loaded` property in the controller is not the same as in the directives' scopes. Try using `$scope.$broadcast` instead of bool flags for notifying your directives everything is ready.

Comment: Have you tried using `$scope.$apply` after changing the value to `true`?

Comment: @JamesBrierley Yes.  It caused an error because a digest was already in effect.

Comment: @fracz the service has its own scope.  The directive has its own scope.  The controller has its own scope.  As you can see, the service links its scope to the service's so it can watch for changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fine way to do things, and I view it as orthogonal to promises (which are indeed extremely useful).  Your problem comes from breaking the linkage you've created with the assignment.  Instead try:

```
$scope.data = MySvc.data;
```

And append to that, e.g. `MySvc.data.loaded = false`.  This way the `data` variable is never reassigned, so your linkage between controller and service stays intact.

Then you can either watch `data.loaded` or watch `data` as a collection by passing true as the 3rd option to `$watch`.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comment, you may have problems with yours scopes overridding the `loaded` property.

Try using the angular events to solve your problem.

```
angular.module('test', [])
.controller 'MyController', ($scope, $timeout) ->
  $timeout ->
    $scope.$broadcast('READY')
  , 2000
.directive 'myDirective', ->
  scope: {}
  template: '<span>{{ value }}</span>'
  link: ($scope) ->
    $scope.value = "I'm waiting to be ready..."
    $scope.$on 'READY', ->
      $scope.value = "I'm ready!!"
```

[See this in action](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOqLJo) (CoffeeScript as it's faster for prototyping but should be clear enough).

Comment: your comment prompted me to realize what was going wrong.  I'm used to doing things this way with objects ... not with simple basic data types.  When I do it with objects, I'm passing along the value of the pointer to the object.  With a simple data type, it's only passing along the value.  I've had an issue with broadcasts taking an exceptionally long time, but your comment has helped me realize the answer, which I will post later, once I have everything hammered out.

Comment: Whatever you end up with, it's impossible that `$watch` will be faster than `$broadcast`. `$watch` is evaluated on every digest cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You're making this complicated. Use promises instead!!! They're sweet. Promises keep state of their resolution.

```
.factory('hello_world', function ($q, $timeout) {
   var promise = $q.defer;
   $timeout(function () {
      promise.resolve('hello world');
   }, 1000)

   return promise.promise;
 })

.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, hello_world) {
   hello_world.then(function (response) {
     console.log("I will only be ran when the async event resolves!");
     console.log(response);
   });
 });
```

As you can see promises are much better, no watches. No weird gates. Simpler, and sexy. ;)